# Another word for an 'upgrade old version to new'

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I am trying to present on a new technology/system that is based off something old... I am struggling to have a catchy title. I want to say something along the lines of:

> 'the old-technology upgraded'

or

> 'old-technology with a face-lift'

...

Comment: I think in this case, it would be a missed opportunity to not put some humour into the presentation. Depending on the crowd something like 'taking off the old-technology's training bra!', and even the face-lift example isn't bad. Humour is a very important part of keeping the audience engaged.

Comment: @Cruncher - I agree. Humor is essential especially in a technical presentation. The title, intro and conclusion need to be able to capture and entertain people enough to have them awake.

Comment: Maybe "refurbish"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider *retrofitted*.

> [*retrofit*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/retrofitted)
>
> - To substitute new or modernized parts or systems for older equipment
> - To provide (a jet, automobile, computer, or factory, for example)
>   with parts, devices, or equipment not in existence or available at
>   the time of original manufacture.

Comment: Thanks this is the word I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try  *old technology revamped.*​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Revamped and amplified were the two that I was thinking before posting the question. But retrofit seems to have an extra edge.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific instance you're asking about, you may want something less specific and more flashy. Perhaps *reimagining*.

> ... the *reimagining* of **[old technology type]**

Answer (score 1):

I would take a common term used in a lot of industries and use it for your case since it seems to fit well.

[remodeled](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/remodel)

> change the structure or form of (something, especially a building,
>   policy, or procedure).

Also the following might work:

- modernized
- reconstructed
- rebuilt

Comment: I like remodeled... but I want the word to have more power... something more dramatic...like a complete make-over

Comment: @Keni - added a couple more with oomph.

Comment: I like 'Reconstructed'! Its got the oomph I was hunting for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: "Classic tech, reenvisioned."

Answer (score 1):

I would consider **'refurbished'** if that makes sense in your context.

Also, it's common to hear about automobiles and the like being **'restored.'**  The connotation here is that it is put back to its original spec and not usually enhanced.

One might also consider **'two point oh'** (2.0), which would signify it's the next generation of such a technology.

> Behold! The Acme Toothbrush 2.0!  It's revolutionary!!!

Comment: I am trying to say that the new technology is a new and improved version of the old one. Refurbished or restored doesn't have the effect I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**[Novantique](http://blog.ocad.ca/wordpress/gdes3b20-su2010-01/3-2-project-two/guia-project-2-concepts/)**: both new and old through repair or imitation

Answer (score 0):

Why not a neologism, such as **nuvo-classic**?

Or you could go for a tongue-in-cheek oxymoron like **up-to-dated**.